# How to autologin in Office-365 in PowerShell script hosted in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I created PowerShell script that runs well in PowerShell-ISE. It autologin with credential popup and works as expected.

Problem: While same script I added to Task Scheduler then it prompts credential and wait until select the user, once user selects manually then it works as expected. But I want autologin and execute without prompt credential.

Command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com" -UseWebLogin
```

Note: Only `-UseWebLogin` option is applicable.

Comment: Why web login only? Is this because of MFA? in that case, you won't be able to automatically run. You need a service account that is exempt from MFA.

Comment: Thank for reply @teylyn I am using service account only which have single password based authentication no MFA enabled.

Comment: Well, using Web login requires the browser as an interface to supply id and password. Why not use the Credentials Manager and store credentials?

Comment: When use -Credential at that time it throws error : "Connecct-PnpOnline : The sign-in name or password doesn ot match one in the Microsoft account system." Even Username and password correct then after it throws same error.